# How can I set Visual Studio to show a stack trace for first chance exceptions?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, exception

Right now, it just shows:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.Stubs.VsPackage.dll

Is there a way I can get it to include a partial stack trace with the exception message without having to break into the debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you seeing this message in the output window or in the exception assistant?

The exception assistant is a little tooltip style window which displays the exception information.  If it's the exception assitant you can click on the "View Detail" button and bring up a property grid.  One of the properties will be the Stack Trace.

If it's the build window I'm afraid there is no way to have it print out the stack trace information with the exception.  You're only option is to enable break on first chance exceptions and manually inspect the value.

Comment: It's the output window. I'm trying to avoid having to use the exception assistant because it's a miserably slow process.